# Get ID of Page in ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a very simple loop in which I want to display some posters, and once clicked to show the popup with the related product. I have created this with a custom post type and with ACF Page Link as field type.

[image]

Now After having created this ACF field for my custom Post type I can select my desired Product (for which I will need the ID) from a Metabox

[image]

My current loop

```
    <ul class="products columns-5">
        <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'posters'); ?>
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
        <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <li class="product" style="width: 330px;">
           <div class="product-inner clearfix">
              <div class="mf-product-thumbnail">
                 <a href="<?php the_field('my_link'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo get_permalink($postID); ?>" class="mf-product-quick-view" tabindex="0"><img width="300" height="450" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full'); ?>" class="" alt=""></a>
              </div>
           </div>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
```

While the a href link works using a custom field, the problem I am currently trying to solve is to get the actual ID of the product as it seems to be required to work with **data-id**. I've tried to add get_permalink($postID);  however this does not seem to be working. Some expert advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use current loop element ID.(default WordPress post object id) 
Code should look like:

```
<ul class="products columns-5">
        <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'posters'); ?>
        <?php $loop = new WP_Query($args); ?>
        <?php if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
 $id = $loop->post->ID;
?>
        <li class="product" style="width: 330px;">
           <div class="product-inner clearfix">
              <div class="mf-product-thumbnail">
                 <a href="<?php the_field('my_link'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="mf-product-quick-view" tabindex="0"><img width="300" height="450" src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full'); ?>" class="" alt=""></a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

**UPDATED:** 
To get linked product link and ID just change your ACF field type to Post Object, set filter by post type(for product -> post type `product`) and set return type to Post object, after that do like ->

```
$linked_product = get_field('my_link');
$id = $linked_product->$post_id;
$link = $linked_product-> (i dont know what object returned exactly just do "var_dump($linked_product)" to chek what is inside).
```

And after that change href and data-id attributed content
[image: ACF field settings]

Comment: Thank you. This however gives me the full url (not id) of the custom post and not the ID of the product I am linking to

Comment: @David, Edited answer, just changed to `data-id="<?php echo $id; ?>"` instead of echo permalink

Comment: Thank you @vlandja - I am getting an ID now - but not the ID of my linked product. Instead I am getting the ID of the Custom Post type. I also edited my first post to clarify this further

Comment: @David, take a look on updated answer, if you have any questions, just ask

Comment: Wow great - please let me try. Thank you!

Comment: @David, if my answer helped you, mark it as answer to help other people find an answer in same situtation